# getting .count(), .exist() from cached queryset without hitting database

Tags: python, django, caching, orm

I am working on a Django app and I want to make several lookups in a queryset.
My problem is subsequent database hits in finding `.count()`

I tried using Django's cache framework but it doesn't seem to work.

This is what I've done so far

```
# app/models.py
from django.core.cache.backends.base import DEFAULT_TIMEOUT
from django.views.decorators.cache import cache_page
from django.core.cache import cache

class my_table(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'table_name'
        
    name                = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    date_created        = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
    ip_address          = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    user                = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        cache.set(self.user , my_table.objects.filter(user=self.user))

        super(my_table, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

I am updating the cache every time the database is updated.

I tried printing `connection.queries` in my views

```
# views.py

def myview(request):
    print(len(connection.queries))                # prints 0
    records = my_table.objects.filter(user=request.user)

    print(records)
    print(len(connection.queries))                # prints 1

    if record.count() > 0:
         # ... some code here

    print(len(connection.queries))                # prints 2
```

`print()` and `.count()` making extra db hits.

Now I tried getting results from the cache

```
# views.py

def myview(request):
    print(len(connection.queries))                # prints 0
    records = cache.get(request.user)

    print(records)
    print(len(connection.queries))                # prints 0 

    if record.count() > 0:
         # ... some code here

    print(len(connection.queries))                # prints 1
```

There was no extra query for `print()` but `.count()` still hitting database.

how can I perform ORM operations on cached queries without hitting the database multiple times?

I want to perform filtering, aggregations, and count/exist on this queryset without hitting the database.

Also, `cache.get(request.user)` returns None after some time.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The [Django source code](https://github.com/django/django/blame/stable/2.2.x/django/db/models/query.py#L386-L390) suggests that calling `.count()` should not hit the database *if* the queryset has already been fully retrieved ([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.count) were only updated in Django 3.2, see [ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/33046), but 2.2 has the same code).

I'm not sure about explicit caches and how that might interact with it, but the above is true if you don't use any explicit cache (it relies on the temporary cache built in to `QuerySet`).

Presumably you're calling `records.count()` rather than `record.count()` (in case `record` happens to exist in your full code and be something else)?